# Amin panel Order grid search is is not working after adding new columns?

Tags: php, collections, magento-1.7, admin, orders

I have added three new columns in admin panel order grid (community ver 1.7.0.2)
But now the search is not working. When I searched by `Purchased On` date it shows the following error message.

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'created_at' in where clause is ambiguous
```

And my collection is as follows.

```
$collection = $observer->getOrderGridCollection();
        $collection->getSelect()
                   ->joinLeft('sales_flat_order_payment', 'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order_payment.parent_id','method')
                   ->joinLeft('customer_entity', 'main_table.customer_id = customer_entity.entity_id','email')
                   ->joinLeft('sales_flat_order_item', 'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order_item.order_id','name');

         $collection->getSelect()->group('main_table.entity_id');
```

Please any suggestions?

Comment: Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should specify table name before field name while use join. like tablename.fieldname.
But where is "created_at" on your code?

Comment: The following tables has 'created_at' columns                       1. customer_entity                                                        2. sales_flat_order_grid                                                  3. sales_flat_order_item

Comment: No. In admin panel order grid is generated by sales_flat_order_grid table. It self has a 'create_at' column. Same way the other tables which I have joined to the sales_flat_order_grid collection, them selves have 'created_at' columns

Comment: try this by changing the coulumn name of a table.

Comment: how to change the table column name?